# web.xml url-pattern - serving both application wide together with more specific

Tags: vaadin, web.xml, jnlp, url-pattern

I'm learning Vaadin and Java web development. Vaadin suggests to redirect all the URLs to `com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet` via use of `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` in web.xml.
I also want to handle some additional URLs with separate servlets, e.g.:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JnlpGenerator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jnlp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is there any way to achive this, while having such a wide pattern, as `/*` is? At my current configuration, any call to e.g. `http://localhost:8080/myapp/applet.jnlp` is ignored, because `/*` takes over and Vaadin application starts up.

I'll appreciate some help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you can extend `com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet`, please do so and use `request.getRequestDispatcher().forward()` to forward your url pattern `*.jnlp` to `JnlpGenerator`. For other URL patterns, do the usual business by calling `super` method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you only need to bind the following URIs to make vaading to work correctly: `/VAADIN/*, /root_URI_for_vaadin_app/*`

Example from one of my projects:

```
@WebServlet(name = "vaadinServlet",
        urlPatterns = {"/app/*", "/VAADIN/*"},
        asyncSupported = false,
        initParams = {@WebInitParam(
                name = "widgetset",
                value = "com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet"
        )}
)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MainUi.class)
public class AppServlet extends VaadinServlet {}
```

Then you can bind any servlet to any URI and they should work correctly together with Vaadin.